# Format the tick in plotly histogram's x-axis

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have the simple dataframe `d` below and I want to creata a histogram based on the frequency of its values. I am trying to set the inital value as `0` and then display the values in the x-axis by `5` but neither of those seems to work since values begin from `1` and then display `8`. I would prefer a clear plotly solution on this as first choice, without `ggplot()` interference.

```
d<-data.frame(c(1,5,7,5,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,15,13))
x <- list(
  tick0=0,
  dtick=5

)

# Create the plotly histogram

plot_ly(alpha = 0.9) %>%
  add_histogram(x = as.factor(d[,1]),source="subset") %>%
  # Add titles in plot and axes
  layout(barmode = "overlay",xaxis=x,margin=list(b=100))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below approaches it a little differently but I think the result is what you are looking for.

```
d<-data.frame(x = c(1,5,7,5,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,15,13))

gg <- ggplot(d, aes(x)) + geom_histogram() + stat_bin(breaks = c(0, 5, 10, 15), binwidth = 5)

ggplotly(gg)
```

Comment: thanks this is useful and may use it but I would prefer a clear plotly solution if exists